# How to backport db_merge() to drupal 6?

Tags: 6, database

I am converting a module from drupal 7 to drupal 6. I have a query in drupal 7.
The query contains function [db_merge()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_merge/7)

```
   db_merge('facebook_rules_user_tokens')
    ->key(array('uid' => $form_state['user']->uid))
    ->fields(array(
      'user_grant' => $form_state['values']['facebook_rules_allow'],
    ))
```

Which function should I use in d6 for the above sql?

Answer (score 2):

From the [MergeQuery docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/class/MergeQuery/7)

```
An ANSI SQL:2003 compatible database would run the following query:

MERGE INTO table_name_1 USING table_name_2 ON (condition)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET column1 = value1 [, column2 = value2 ...]
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (column1 [, column2 ...]) VALUES (value1 [, value2 ...

Other databases (most notably MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite) will emulate this statement by running a SELECT and then INSERT or UPDATE.
```

1. You need to do a `SELECT` using [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.mysql-common.inc/function/db_query/6) first, to find out if your data already exists.
2. Then you can use [drupal_write_record](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/6), which will do either an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT` depending on whether or not you populate the tables primary key(s).

Comment: I find it very odd that there's no mention of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in those docs (the MySQL specific merge query syntax). Seems like it would have been a very easy thing to implement for merge queries in the MySQL driver, and eliminate the inefficiency of 2 queries. I never even considered that they hadn't implemented it, didn't realise I was using such inefficient queries. To the patching board...

Comment: @Clive Looking at the code, I can't see any driver implementing an efficient version. There might be room for a core patch here. :) On the other hand, do you really do that many merges?

Comment: Yes. Yes I do. ;)

Comment: @Clive I'd be interesting in seeing what you come up with. :)